# Do the electrical codes have a solution to extend a cable that is short?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

There is an existing wire that was feeding a vanity light on a wall close to the light switch. I want to re-purpose it to feed a string of three LED lights and obviously the wire is to short to reach to the nearest LED pot light.

It is going to be a pain to pull this cable out and replace it with a longer one
What can be done to extend it using a safe and compliant with the electrical code solution?

This is a NMD 14/2 electrical cable, 15 AMP circuit, feeds light bulbs (LED)

Specs here of the wire I'm using:
https://www.rona.ca/en/wire-nmd90-14-2-47174851-1798029

Comment: Photo didn't attach... or more detail, what cable? where? how much access to the route to the other end?

Comment: Where is this cable and what kind of cable is it?  Answers will vary depending on that.  And if you could add a picture of the cable in question, that would be even better.

Comment: damn sorry...I will be more clear see the updates please

Comment: How far are you attempting to extend it?  Is the existing wire in use and terminate in a J-Box?  Are is it a new wiring circuit that the wire was cut too short to where you want to terminate?

Comment: One end is attached to the box with light switches. The other one is free and it was used as described in the initial post. The wire is too short to reach the point where I want my first LED light

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some splicing methods permitted inside walls, but ordinary wire nuts are not.

The usual solution is to use a junction box, with or without anything else in the box. For example, if your cable goes to a light fixture and you want to replace it with another light fixture a few feet away, connect the old & new cables with wire nuts inside the existing box, cover it with a blank plate, and run the new cable to a new box where you want it. The cover plate has to be accessible, but it can be painted or wallpapered to match your wall or ceiling, or hidden behind a picture. It just needs to be accessible without any special tools (except a screwdriver to remove the usual two screws holding it onto the box).

Comment: what is the reason behind that requirement "must be accessible"

Comment: I don't know for sure, since I was not involved in writing the NEC :-) , but I suspect it is because connections - whether wire nuts or anything else - go bad far more often than the wires themselves. An imperfect connection combined with cumulative effects of vibration or other problems can go bad - possibly years after installation. If you have a problem with a circuit, anything accessible is easy to fix. But inside the walls - hard to know where the problem is and even harder to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I still do remodels.   These bad boys are worth their weight in gold.
**300 V Nonmetallic Splice**
[image]

My grainger carries these but I still make sure I have at least two in stock at my house.   The last thing I want is two of my guys spending 4 hours trying to figure out how to run a cable without opening 5 things... and honestly causing more issues.   https://www.grainger.com/product/TE-CONNECTIVITY-300-V-Nonmetallic-Splice-6HKE8

These are perfectly by code in updated NEC.   Also if you compare these to the smaller tyco splice kits - this is something that you trust more in a wall and most of all your inspector will appreciate this compared to the cheaper (still legal) splice kits.

(and I am sure Harper or one of the other guys can give you the code allowance.  I just fix crap, not a master electrician.)

Comment: ok now I am confused. Can I use these without a box and hide them in the wall or I still need to make them accessible
The electrician who installed the box I am looking at the three ring one that hosts the switch that control that cable attached that box to the stud with a screw that I can't reach ...without that I can't pull out the cable although my guess is that the cable is stapled somewhere on the stud as well and it won't move even if I remove the box

Comment: Those were designed to be used without a box with existing wiring.  But you have a pre-existing junction box that the extension wire can be connected.  Make the connection at the existing junction box, place a blank cover per previous answer.  This is why I asked all the questions before, The approved splice kit is not for removing a junction box so you can hide the connection in the wall.<br/>  You would attach the new wire at the existing light fixture and extend it to the new location.

Comment: If there is a different issue of why you cannot use the existing light fixture box as a junction box,  then repost the question to the actual issue you are having in doing this the normal way.

Comment: @MiniMe - this answers your question.   If you have a junction box or outlet that you can use, that would be preferred.   This splice kit is rated to be installed in a wall to extend a circuit (completely compliant) with a box.   That's it.

Comment: sounds like take my word for it and I can't do that I need to see a section of the code that says that

Comment: @MiniMe - I gave you the best answer on here and you come up with a jerk statement.   I am not your librarian.   RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

In wall splice kits do exists, but they are pretty bulky. Search for Tyco Electronics Romex Splice kit for one example.

I've heard from electricians they can be hard to wire so I've always used an accessible junction box or just dug the cable out and replaced it repairing the drywall after.